# Finding the centre of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I am trying to find the centre of the equation mentioned in part c), but I can only really understand the "long way" of doing it (i.e., finding the intersection of the prependicular bisectors of $PT$ and $QT$). In the marking scheme, the quickest way of doing it is to find the midpoint of $QT$. This implies that $QT$ is a diameter but I simply cannot undretsand this since it seems to me that it certainly can be a chord. My question  is whether we can, with the information given,  detail why exactly $PQ$ is a diameter.

[image: problem statement]

Thanks

(Note: By part "c" I mean "A second circle...")

Comment: What is part c? Please fill in the relevant information so that your question is not closed for lack of context.

Comment: I have added a picture but it's not working. This is the link [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/K4GwO.jpg

Comment: There's no picture even in the ilnk provided

Comment: Are you sure? When I click it loads up a picture.

Comment: @Element118 Thanks for the edit.

Comment: [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem) will help here.

Comment: @Element118 Thanks a lot, that's all I needed.